# Unable to Set up Bottom Tab Navigation with Stack Navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I'm using both Stack Navigation and Bottom Tab Navigation to navigate inside my app

**Stack Navigation** is basically set up like this:

*WelcomeScreen --> SignInScreen <--> SignUpScreen --> HomeScreen*

Now, I wanted to use a **Bottom Tab Navigation** to navigate between my HomeScreen and MyGamesScreen

*HomeScreen <--> MyGamesScreen*

The only screens I wanted to display the Bottom Tab Navigator were in HomeScreen and MyGamesScreen.

I tried a couple of tutorials and my last attempt was looking at the Documentation page on [Nesting Navigators](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators), but it did not work for me. I was either getting my Bottom Tab Navigator to be displayed in all pages or not show up in any.

This is my **App.js** and it currently is not showing my Bottom Tab Navigator in the HomeScreen. I tried switching the name of my function to 'HomeScreen' as a way to solve it, like the documentation shows, but it gives me an error saying that 'HomesScreen' has already been declared.

```js
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'; 
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs'; 


import LoadingScreen from '/Users/toxnd/Documents/MaisJogo/MaisJogoApp/screens/LoadingScreen'
import WelcomeScreen from '/Users/toxnd/Documents/MaisJogo/MaisJogoApp/screens/WelcomeScreen'
import SignInScreen from '/Users/toxnd/Documents/MaisJogo/MaisJogoApp/screens/SignInScreen'
import SignUpScreen from '/Users/toxnd/Documents/MaisJogo/MaisJogoApp/screens/SignUpScreen'
import HomeScreen from '/Users/toxnd/Documents/MaisJogo/MaisJogoApp/screens/HomeScreen'
import MyGamesScreen from '/Users/toxnd/Documents/MaisJogo/MaisJogoApp/screens/WelcomeScreen'


const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export function Home() {

  return (
    
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name='Meus Jogos' component={MyGamesScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>

    );
}


export default function App() {


  return (
<NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Loading"
      screenOptions={{
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#BB2CD9',
        },
        headerTintColor: '#fff',
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight: 'bold',
        },
        }}>
        
        <Stack.Screen
          options={{headerShown: false}}
              name='Loading' component={LoadingScreen} />
          
        <Stack.Screen
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
              name='Welcome' component={WelcomeScreen} />
          
        <Stack.Screen
          options={{headerShown: false}}
              name="Sign In" component={SignInScreen} />
          
        <Stack.Screen
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        name='Sign Up' component={SignUpScreen} /> 
      
       <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />

      </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on quick look it looks like you used the `HomeScreen` twice, which is conflicting with the import of `HomeScreen`, consider a different name for the tab navigator variable.

Comment: Do you mean in 'export function HomeScreen() ' ? I switched to just 'Home' and the Bottom Tab Navigator did not show up

Comment: you have to change it here too `<Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />`

Comment: Got It! Thanks! It was a dumb mistake